# Error message in spyder, upgrade requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I am receiving the following error message in spyder.

Warning: You are using requests version , which is older than requests-oauthlib expects, please upgrade to 2.0.0 or later.

I am not sure how i upgrade requests. I am using python 2.7 as part of an anaconda installation

Comment: try `conda install requests>=2`

Answer (score 0):

According to [pip install docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/) :

```
-U, --upgrade

Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. 
The handling of dependencies depends on the upgrade-strategy used.
```

You could try this :

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I was me with "Requirement already up to date..."

Answer (score 0):

You should try `conda install requests>=2`, so conda will take care of all dependencies and try to install a version of `requests` above 2.0.0